# Storing a PDO select query to php variable

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to store the result of a PDO select query to a variable so that I can call that variable to an INSERT statement,

Is there a possible way to do that?

Here is my normal SQL code and I want to convert it in PDO:

```
$resultbrgy = mysql_query("SELECT BarangayName FROM npos.ref_barangay WHERE BarangayID=$brgy");
$barangayname=mysql_result($resultbrgy, 0);
```

I'm having a hard time working on a conversion for mysql_result, the `$barangayname` will be the variable I will use to execute another SQL which is an INSERT statement.

Comment: atleast take some courtesy to share your code..

Comment: Huh? What have you tried? What's not working on `$result = $pdoStatement->`[`fetchall()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) ?

Answer (score 0):

I just solved my problem, I store the value returned inside an array and make an = $variable;

```
    `foreach($result as $row1) {
    }
    $barangayname=$row1['BarangayName'];`
```